# how to set a home page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in codeIgniter..Im trying to create an anchor tag to link my home page from home page like this

main-nav.php

```
<li>
     <?php echo anchor('Welcome/home', 'Home', 'class="icon icon-photo"') ?>
</li>
```

but when I click the home button its show me a blank page in staid the main page or the same page.

in my controller
here is my code

Welcome.php

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{   
    $this->home();
}

public function home() {
    $this->load->model('model_books');
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('url');


    $data['books_details'] = $this->model_books->getBookDetails();
    $data['title'] = 'NMSC Online Library';
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/main_nav');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('main_body');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
}
```

what im trying to do is i have a main page that have a button that link into  own page i mean the main page. ( main page link to main page ).
I knew how to link a page in pure html like this..

```
<a href="home.php"> Home </a>
```

but in codeigniter i cant. pls help.
 thanks and advance..

in my controller i have a  Welcome.php
the code is shown already above.

in views folder there is a folder name templates inside of it i have a main_nav.php. the code is

```
 <body>


    <div class="container">
        <!-- Push Wrapper -->
        <div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">

            <!-- mp-menu -->
            <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
                <div class="mp-level">
                    <h2 class="icon icon-world">All Categories</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Staff</a </li>
                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                            <a class="icon icon-news" href="#">Events & Activities</a>
                            <div class="mp-level">
                                <h2 class="icon icon-news">Events & Activities</h2>
                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Orientation Schedule</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Linkages</a></li>

                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                            <a class="icon icon-news" href="#">Databases</a>
                            <div class="mp-level">
                                <h2 class="icon icon-news">Databases</h2>
                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Proquest</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">E-books Open Access</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Journals Open Access</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Low Online Resources</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Medical & Nursing Resources</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Thesis & Dissertations</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">News Online Resources</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Other Online Resources</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Service Hours</a></li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">WebLIS-OPAC</a></li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Library System</a></li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">New Acquisitions</a></li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">The Librarian</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- /mp-menu -->
        <div class="scroller"><!-- this is for emulating position fixed of the nav -->
```

i wold link that homepage button to the same page..

in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /nmsc-online-library/

# If your project is in server root then should be: RewriteBase /
# If project is in folder then it should be: RewriteBase /folder_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: try this  <a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/?">Welcome</a> or 
<a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home/?">Welcome</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To set Home Controller**

Goto `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "controller_name/method"; 
#if you define you first method inside index() then no need of entering method in second parameter.
```

**And create link to another controller.**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/aboutUs">About Us</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/product">Products</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/corsair">Corsair</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/contact">Contact Us</a>
```

> > If you place `.htaccess` file the you can remove `index.php` in above URL

**EDIT 01**

In `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: sir the anchor tag generate me a code look like this <a href="http://::1/nmsc-online-library/">Home</a>

Comment: Just call me Abdulla or ab. What is your base URL??

Comment: abdulla my base url is localhost/nmsc-online-library. in my config folder $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: keep base URL empty. and try

Comment: i have a .htaccess in my project.

Comment: its ok. remove base url and place htaccess as same and try

Comment: i set my anchor like this <a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Welcome</a> and my base_url in config.php is set emty already... but generate me like this... <a  href="http://::1/nmsc-online-library/">Welcome</a>

Comment: where do i place the htaccess ab? at my base_url? i put my htaccess in my project folder already..

Comment: it wont hapen. it will show the correct data. make sure you are not setting any base_url manually

Comment: ab is there a possible that .htaccess can cause a problem like this?

Comment: @McGyverBasaya i have added htaccess place that

Comment: what syntax i should replace ab? there are many RewriteCond and RewriteRule in their.

Comment: remove all and paste mine

Comment: i changed all the content of .htaccess with your code then when im trying, it diverting to xampp dashboard not in my project folder..

Comment: my base url is localhost/nmsc-online-library but when i browse that the url change into http://localhost/dashboard/

Comment: remove that. Keep baseurl empty

Comment: thanks for your concern,, no i don't have teamwiver but if that can help me  a lot then I should get that right now..

Comment: @McGyverBasaya remove pwd

Comment: thanks ab but my problem is i cant link a homepage using anchor tag in codeigniter.. can you do that to me again in dreamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<li>
    <?php echo anchor("", "Home", array("target" => "_self")); ?>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but its show me up same problem and generate me a code    
     <li><a href="http://::1/nmsc-online-library/conrroller/Welcome/home" class="icon icon-photo">Home</a

Comment: in config you can set configuration on your site. $config['base_url'] = ''; $config['index_page'] = ''; and $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; is the welcome controller place on conrroller folder?

Comment: sir I have another problem maybe this is the reason why your code did't work... I delete my home button what you given then refresh the browser but i see my home button was not remove in my page, I save my text editor and exit all my text editor also i restart the local server then run again but same problem my button that i removed is always there,,, how that happen? I remove that already but the button is always there...

Comment: oke. first i need to see your routes.php file inside config folder.

Comment: <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: first change $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'; to $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome/home';

Comment: sir maybe there was a problem to my codeigniter, even I change already the link using your code it doesn't change the code in the browser..

Comment: maybe you edit wrong file. tell me where you place your project?

Comment: sir work fine but not the home button..  the link doesn't change even I remove some parts of css files doesn't change my page.. I don't know what happen to this, maybe I will fix this first before this problem..

Comment: what browser you use? if you are using chrome you can clear cache using Ctrl+r. or you can use inconigto mode. maybe it cause by cache

Comment: Im using xampp server then I put my project inside the htdocs. my project name is nmsc-online-library... my text editor is sublime. in top of sublime i see the url of my main-nav is inside the views folder...

Comment: $this->load->view('templates/main_nav'); change to $this->load->view('main_nav');

Comment: if you want to put main_nav inside /project/application/view/templates you need to create templates folder. then put main_nav inside templates

Comment: sir anchor tag generate me a code like this <a href="http://::1/nmsc-online-library/Wilcome" class="icon icon-photo">Home</a> what thats http://::1/ means? by the way i found out that i have a 2 main_nav.php in my views folder same as you said..

Comment: it means you are call website in your local computer. ::1 same like 127.0.0.1 or localhost. where localhost is your virtual host.

Comment: you need to learn how to use view corectly. please read this  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?highlight=view

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your li tag if your controller name is welcome

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/"></a>
```

or if its Welcome then change it to

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/"></a>
```

Comment: sir its shown me a blank page then anchor tag generate me a code <a  href="http://::1/nmsc-online-library/index.php/Welcome/?">Welcome</a> im confusing why im facing this http://::1/ in my anchor tag, whats that it mean?

Comment: or do it like this <a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/"></a>
or maybe <a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/"></a> and for this inside the index {
$this->load->view('main_body');
}

Comment: for the first line of code, make the "welcome" first letter either Capital or small to see if it works..